# Checking unbiased parameter

Tags: r, parameters, linear-regression

I'm doing linear regression with R right now and I was wondering if there's a R function to test  whether a parameter is unbiased or biased.

```
summary(regression model)
anova(regression model)
```

These two functions do not seem to indicate anything about whether a parameter is unbiased. I would appreciate any kinds of advice. Thank you.

Comment: You can only *prove* unbiased, R's statistical software cannot tell you.

Comment: agree with the previous comment (and linear regression *does* provide unbiased estimates -- see any mathematical statistics book).  If you want you can test bias by simulation, but there would be little point (except as an exercise) for linear regression, since we know the answer analytically.